# Validations of associated has_many depending on status attribute (invoices and invoice lines)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got the following models:

- An Invoice has several statuses: Initially it's "draft", then it can be "sent", and "payed"
- An Invoice has_many InvoiceLines. InvoiceLines have a text and a cost.

My question is: How can I perform the following validations?

If the Invoice Status is not draft:

- No InvoiceLines can be added to it
- The values of the invoiceLines can't be modified

Right now I've got this, but it's not working:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoice_lines
  validates_associated :invoice_lines
end

class InvoiceLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  validate :check_invoice_status

  def check_invoice_status
    unless self.invoice.draft?
      errors.add_to_base "Can't add or modify: the invoice status is not draft"
    end
  end
end
```

This does not work as intented since the validates_associated "allways fails"; once the invoice status is changed to "sent", the invoice lines are allways invalid. I only want them to be checked if "updated" or "added new".

Thaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use "changed?" for invoice line:

```
def validate_invoice_status
  if changed? and !invoice.draft?
    errors.add_to_base "Can't add or modify: the invoice status is not draft"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    def check_invoice_status
        unless self.invoice.draft?
          self.reload if changed? && !new_record?
          errors.add_to_base("Can't add: the invoice status is not draft") if new_record?
        end
      end
```

Comment: This will still "allways add an error" - I believe the changed? bit has to be part of the condition, too:
    if changed? and !self.invoice.draft?
makes more sense here.
Also, I like the idea of reloading, but I don't think it will be necesary in this case - since the validations will prevent any update. Thanks for commenting anyway.

Comment: I have never encountered this problem, but i logically:
we can have 2 situation:
1. when creating invoice_line 'new_record?'==true, 'changed?'==true
check_invoice_status should add an error, because we haven't record in database and we haven't permissions to create it
2. when updating current invoice_line, new_record? == false, but changed? == true, on this case we should reload invalid record, that we have now, from database, our record become valid, and validates_associated should pass it.
Anyway, good that you found a way how to catch this.